# Auto Generated id using mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I am developing a desktop application using windows forms c#, I've created an unique index named Id in my database.

But now I want it when I send a class with field 'Id' empty so the database gives it a unique value by its own.

I am sorry for not illustrating well and also the problem may seem easy, but I don't know how because i am still a beginner

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, MongoDB generates unique ObjectId for `_id` field. You can use it. For other cases, you need to [generate manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394800/how-to-use-auto-increment-field-in-mongo-c-sharp-driver-without-using-eval)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a unique index yourself. MongoDB creates a unique index on the [_id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-id-field) field during the creation of a collection.

If an inserted document omits the _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) for the _id field. ObjectId essentially a timestamp plus random value.

In your models, you can map to _id field using attributes

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But the problem here is that it is not human readable, i want an id that i can show in a list when i show a list of documents in my collection.

Comment: You can set _id manually, but there is no auto-increment functionality out of the box. You can do something like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm